# Android Ffmpeg- Root Permission not granted to "su" Working Directory:null

Tags: android, process, ffmpeg, android-ndk, processbuilder

I have compiled ffmpeg for android using ndk r10e on os x but it does not produce ffmpeg.so. All other libraries are generated. I have been searching this for over a week. I have tried various methods to execute ffmpeg command but none were successful. I used

```
Process p=new ProcessBuilder("su /data/data/com.example.ffmpegtem/").start();

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                getBaseContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir); 

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()); 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 700 /data/data/com.example.ffmpegtem/app_bin/ffmpeg");
```

All resulted in IOException-Working Directory: null. I also tried Shell Callback method provided by Github android ffmpeg library project which resulted in Nullpointerexception. I have written read/write permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Convert 1 image to video code:

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(chperm.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("-loop 1 -i " + inpath + " -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 "+outpath);
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to run ffmpeg cmd in Android enviroment? Why not use it programatically? You could try a library here https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ffmpeg+android and write some code to achieve your goal.

Comment: I used https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java but  shell callback is giving null pointer exception

Comment: File folder = new File(FOLDER_PATH);
if (!folder.exists()) {
folder.mkdir();
}
String inpath = FOLDER_PATH + "/img.jpg";
  String outpath = FOLDER_PATH + "/out.mp4";
File f = new File(outpath);
Clip clip = new Clip(inpath);
try {
FfmpegController controller = new FfmpegController(this, f);
controller.convertImageToMP4(clip, 10, outpath, new ShellCallback() {
public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
 }public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
}});